# Which capability exists only in java.io.FileWriter?

Tags: java, stream, java-io, filewriter, buffering

Which capability exists only in `java.io.FileWriter`?

A. Closing an open stream.

B. Flushing an open stream.

C. Writing to an open stream.

D. Writing a line separator to an open stream.

I know its not D since line separator is only written using BufferedWriter's newLine() method. But I am not sure which is the correct answer. I have posted this question only after not being able to find the answer.

Please advise.

Comment: Advice: don't use `FileWriter` in 2015; use java.nio.file and `Files.newBufferedWriter()` instead. Also, "only in FileWriter" as opposed to what else?

Comment: "*only*" as opposed to what? What are you comparing it to?

Comment: I guess this originally came from a list of questions, which (hopefully) established the context.

Comment: **Every part** of this question is answered by the Javadoc.

Comment: All 4 are available in other JCL classes, too. For example `PrintWriter` has `close()`, `flush()`, `write()` and `println()`. Besides I think it is technically wrong to speak about a `Stream` in those cases. Compared to `FileOutputStream` (or `OutputStream`) it is the `println()`

Answer (score 0):

Technically I don't think any of these are correct. In any Java version I can find, none of these are unique to `FileWriter`.

In fact, [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) doesn't implement `flush()`, but [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) does.

Aside from direct use or direct subclassing, I can't think of anything builtin besides `FileWriter` that extends `OutputStreamWriter`, so that should point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is : D. Writing a line separator to an open stream.

Explanations:
A newLine() method is provided in BufferedWriter which is not in FileWriter.